# Facebook photo permissions fail to give access to photos

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have created a facebook app that if users of it accept should give the app and its access token to their photo albums. The website access the info from is authorized in the app.

(Yes the users im trying to get photos from have accepted and allowed the app)

However it doesn't work, it just returns nothing.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/10100188540131028/photos?access_token=(access_token_here)

{
   "data": [

   ]
}
```

The app requests permissions for basic info and user_photos.

Am i missing something here? The only photos i can access are on public "pages". (which i can do without the app)

Comment: it happened to me several times because of a wrong token ...

Comment: can u expand on that anymore?

Comment: Just double check if you are using the correct token, try it to get other infos for example

Comment: w00t, you were right!!! =D thnks <3 <3

Comment: i'll add it as an answer so, so that the question will be concidered as solved :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is usally due to incorrect token, double check it.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks a lot it Works

Set user_photos permission for the 'scope' parameter while accessing token.

login page

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id='123'&scope=read_stream,user_photos
```